# ideal and ideal classes in the ring of integers.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> (I'm studying Pierre Samuel's Algebraic theory of numbers.) Let $K$ be
>   a number field of degree $n$, $d$ the absolute discriminant of $K$,
>   and $\mathfrak{a}$ a nonzero integral ideal of $K$. Then
>   $\mathfrak{a}$ contains a nonzero element $x$ such that $$|N_{K/Q}(x)|
>  \le \left(\frac4{\pi}\right)^{r_2}\frac{n!}{n^n}|d|^{1/2}N(\mathfrak{a})$$ and
>   every ideal class of $K$ contains an integral ideal $\mathfrak{b}$
>   such that $$N(\mathfrak{b}) \le
>  \left(\frac4{\pi}\right)^{r_2}\frac{n!}{n^n}|d|^{1/2}$$

Let $A$ be the ring of integers(elements of $K$ which are integral over $\mathbb{Z}$). But is it possible to show that the above theorems also holds for any ideal of $A$, and any ideal class of $A$? In other words for the first theorem, given an ideal $I$ of $A$ is it possible to show that $I$ is also an ideal of $K$ and a nonzero element $x$ can be found to be in $A$? and for the second one, given any ideal class of $A$ is it possible to show that it is in ideal class of $K$ and the integral ideal can be found in $A$?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Minkowski's bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_bound). I personally don't think that it makes much sense to talk about the ideals of a number field (a field's only ideals are the zero ideal and itself), and even less sense to talk about its ideals as separate from its ring of integers' given the context: here the integral ideals of $K$ are *precisely* the integral ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$, its ring of integers, so your first statement is true.

As to your second statement, again, it doesn't really make much sense to talk about the ideal classes of $K$ and $\mathcal{O}_K$ as different things. The ideal class group is defined as the quotient of the fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ by the principal fractional ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$. But what you are essentially asking is true: every ideal class in $\text{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_K)$ is represented by an integral ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ with norm at most $\mu_K=\left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^{r_2}\frac{n!}{n^n}\sqrt{|d|}$.